# How do I wait for data to load before it renders the page when clicked onto a link in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

The app was built in a way that you can't go straight to a specified url. So I can't do `cy.visit(#specifiedURL)`... So I need to do this:

```
cy.get('btn')
  .click()
  .then(() => {
     cy.wait(#alias);
  });
```

So when clicked onto that button it redirects me to a new page of the app but I need the data to load before rendering the page...

Answer (score 1):

Cypress waits for any command(click() or type() etc...) for 4 secs by default and click() method will be invoked irrespective of page is loaded or not after 4 secs.

So In order to wait for page to fully load, you need to tell cypress to wait how long in cypress.json file and you can specify with `"pageLoadTimeout": 10000` in cypress.json

```
{
  "integrationFolder": "cypress/integration",
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 10000,
  "pageLoadTimeout": 10000
}
```

Change to something like above and then, first cypress get method will not invoke until 10 secs of `pageLoadTimeout` and then cypress makes query for `get` method. If you have specific requirement of timeouts, just read the documentation here https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Timeouts

Answer (score 0):

You could wait for an element on the next page to be visible to ensure the page has loaded properly if you want.